# US passport holder visa to turkey fromega Germany

Tags: visas, us-citizens, turkey

I am American visiting in Germany .. do I need visa to enter turkey ? If yes what are the process? Since I am American visiting in Germany. .

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes you do need visa. You can get at the Turkish consular office in Germany or online.

http://www.mfa.gov.tr/visa-information-for-foreigners.en.mfa